# Python - Dictionary help, checking if a char is in a dictionary object

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, input, char

I have a dictionary object;

```
secret = {"word" : secretWord}
```

`secretWord` being an argument for a string with a single word inside. I also have a string generating an asterisk (`*`) for every character in the `secretWord`. In my code I have input from the user which gives a letter.

What I wish to accomplish is to check within the dictionary object `secretWord`, and if so, replace any asterisk with the input where relevant. However I am not sure how to then save this as a new argument, and then use the next input on the new argument.

Sorry if my question/problem isn't clear, as I am struggling how to word it.

What I want to happen:

for example the secretWord could be `'PRECEDENCE'`

```
>>>
WORD : **********
Guess a letter: e
**E*E*E**E
Guess a letter: p
P*E*E*E**E
etc
```

What happens:

```
>>>
WORD : **********
Guess a letter: e
**E*E*E**E
Guess a letter: p
P*********
etc
```

My current Code:

```
import random
import sys

def diction(secretWord, lives):

    global guess
    global secret

    secret = {"word" : secretWord, "lives" : lives}
    guess = len(secret["word"]) * "*"
    print (secret["word"])
    print ("WORD: ", guess) 

fileName = input("Please insert file name: ")

def wordGuessed(guess, secret):
    if guess == secret["word"]:
        print ("word is guessed")
    if guess != secret["word"]:
        print ("word is not guessed")

def livesLeft(inpu):
    if inpu not in secret["word"]:
        secret["lives"] = secret["lives"] - 1
        print("Lives left: ", secret["lives"])
    if inpu in secret["word"]:
        print("Correct guess")
        print(secret["lives"])


def guessCheck(inpu):
    for char in secret["word"].lstrip():
        if char == inpu:
            print (char, end= "")
        elif char != secret["word"]:
            print ("*", end="")


try:
    f = open(fileName)
    content = f.readlines()
except IOError as e :
    f = None
    print("Failed to open", fileName, "- program aborted")
    sys.exit()

Run = True

while Run == True:
    levelIn = input("Enter difficulty (easy, intermediate or hard): ").lower()
    if levelIn == ("easy"):
        lives = 10

    elif levelIn == ("intermediate"):
        lives = 8

    elif levelIn == ("hard"):
        lives = 5

    else:
        print("Please input a valid difficulty.")
        break



    secretWord = (random.choice(content))
    secretWord = secretWord.replace("\n", "")


    diction(secretWord, lives)
    wordGuessed(guess, secret)

    while secret["lives"] > 0:
        inpu = input("Guess a letter: ").upper()
        livesLeft(inpu)
        guessCheck(inpu)
    if secret["lives"] == 0:
        print ("You have no lives left – you have been hung!")
        print ("The word was,", secret["word"])
```

Comment: So you are implementing a hangman game. Can you show us your code please?

Comment: What's your current code for the process?

Comment: @JAL For the whole current program, the code has been added. Sorry if it's messy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the guesses made *so far*, and use those to display the word. Use a set to track what the player already guessed at:

```
guessed = set()
```

So that you can do:

```
if inpu in guessed:
    print('You already tried that letter!')
else:
   guessed.add(inpu)
```

whenever a user makes a guess.

You can then use that set to display the word revealed so far:

```
for char in secret["word"].lstrip():
    if char in guessed:
        print (char, end="")
    else:
        print ("*", end="")
```

Comment: where should I place the code to check if the guessed letter has already been imputed?

Comment: @SeanBrackenborough: as close to the input given as possible; it also depends on wether or not you want to count a re-guess as a lost life.

Comment: I've tried putting in the code to check if the input is in the set already, straight under the input of the letter, yet when I run the program it does implement the if or else statements

Comment: @SeanBrackenborough: sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that. Perhaps you could post a new question with your altered code?